# Required property doesn't work for array of ObjectId type in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have the following schema and model for mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    first_name: String,
    second_name: String,
    roles: { type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role' }], required: true }
});

userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function() {
    return `${this.first_name} ${this.second_name}`;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I can't get `required` to work for arrays of `ObjectId`, when I create an object without the roles field and save it mongoose doesn't throw and error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try adding validation to the roles like this? `validate: v => v == null || v.length > 0`  as described [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5139). Empty array validation worked in mongoose V4, but it changed in V5 https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html#array-required

Comment: Awesome this works thanks, if you answer I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Curous tho `v => v == null || v.length > 0` this fails if the array length is 0 but also fails if the array is null?

Comment: returning false or throwing an error means validation failed.

Comment: can you check my answer? Maybe the validate logic in that link is not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose V4 the required on the array worked as you wanted.

But in V5 this behavior has been [changed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html#array-required).

> In mongoose 5 the required validator only verifies if the value is an
>   array. That is, it will not fail for empty arrays as it would in
>   mongoose 4.

But you can use the validate function to make it work. Returning false or throwing an error means validation failed.

So if you want to validation to fail when the array is null or empty, you can use the following validate function.

```
validate: v !== null && v.length > 0
```

Test:

```js
const validate = (v) => {
  return v !== null && v.length > 0;
};

const res1 = validate(null);
console.log(res1); // FALSE  => Validation fails

const res2 = validate([]);
console.log(res2); //FALSE  => Validation fails

const res3 = validate([1, 2]);
console.log(res3); //TRUE
```